# Tiny MCE - Stopping wrapping of images

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using the TinyMCE Editor, after some Googling it is apparent that the editor needs a root element, which by default is a paragraph.

So everything wrapped in a p tag `<p></p>`

However, I don't want my images to be wrapped in a paragraph as I want them to be a standalone item.

I know you can strip all p tags but can you be selective with the imagery?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to do this within TinyMCE. You could always strip the root `<p>` tag on content export.

Comment: That's disappointing, I suppose I could try and strip the p tags nearest to the img tags?